# How can I serve crossdomain.xml file on a specific port?

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, flash, cross-domain, port

Let me introduce my problem step by step:

I was using a socket connection on the address www.mydomain.com:1925 to provide a chat service for my users. When I moved to cloudflare, I could not connect to port 1925 directly because of the fact that my requests were reaching my origin server over cloudflare and the port was changing.

How did I solve it?
I created a subdomain chat.mydomain.com whose DNS settings point to my origin server not cloudflare. I bypassed cloudflare by this way and I connected my chat service by using chat.mydomain.com:1925 on the browser. So far so good.

Here is the problem.
I am also using Flash and AS3. It is the core of my game on the site. Chat is working on html and my game in flash is in some part of my website. In flash, I was sending scores of players using again a socket connection on www.mydomain.com:1925 by a different namespace.(Since swf's host and url's host matched, I didn't have any problem I think).Since I have changed the domain to chat.mydomain.com:1925, Flash started to request a crossdomain.xml on chat.mydomain.com:1925. There is a crossdomain.xml file on chat.mydomain.com however I cannot serve it from chat.mydomain.com:1925. Here is my code:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("https://chat.mydomain.com/crossdomain.xml");
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader ();
var url:String = "https://chat.mydomain.com:1925/socket.io/1/";                                 

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;     

urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,ioErrorHandler);
urlLoader.load(request);
```

Since flash cannot find crossdomain.xml by getting 404, the requests in my code do not work. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. The URLRequest was trying to connect https://chat.example.com:1925/socket.io/1/. Since the swf was on the domain https://www.example.com, the swf was asking for https://chat.example.com:1925/crossdomain.xml. The port did not understand the https since it was used for my websocket. So I could not find any way to call this request in the swf. Then, I came up with an idea that I can call this url outside of the swf. Since I needed only handshakeid, I called this function via javascript. After getting the response, I loaded my swf by giving the handshakeid as an argument. That has solved my problem. For ones who need to call a function like this dynamically, they can use ExternalInterface calls. I hope it helps.